# Is there a way to send a document to Google Docs instead of downloading it to your drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I want to send a document to Google Docs instead of downloading it to my PC and then uploading it to Google Docs. Is there an easy way to do it (I'm using Chrome)?

Answer (score 3):

The [gPDF for Google Docs Viewer](http://www.chrome-plugins.info/en/183/gpdf-for-google-docs-viewer/) will provide a link to open PDF documents in Google Docs.

**Update:** Just found that Google also has an extension, [Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn), which does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I prefer something like a context menu option (instead of download, "open in docs") becouse most of the docs I need to download are redirect type links

Comment: Check out Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn

Comment: It doesn't work for intranet sites and sites that require authentication. I was hoping for a solution that downloads the document first to your computer and then automatically uploads it to Google Drive and then opens it.

Answer (score 3):

ditto: Google has released a Chrome extension for just this.  It will open the document in chrome directly in a google docs viewer tab and give you the opportunity to save to your google docs if you chose.  Check it out: [Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn)

Comment: Doesn't really help me, the site I am using doesn't have .pdf at the end of the links to the files, so it doesn't recognize them.